# Hibernate: Looking for a way to simplify how I search for objects using an object

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate Core 3.3.4.GA.  I'm looking for a way to simplify my code (if possible).  Right now, I want to search for objects of type "MyObj" using an instance of MyObj, which will be partially populated.  So I have …

```
// inputObj is a partially populated object of type MyObj
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyObj.class);
if (inputObj.getField1() != null) { 
    crit.add( Restrictions.eq( "field1", inputObj.getField1() );
}
if (inputObj.getField2() != null) { 
    crit.add( Restrictions.eq( "field2", inputObj.getField2() );
}
…
List objects = crit.list();
```

Problem is, there is more than 20 fields, so the code is onerous.  Is there a way to simplify the above?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [org.hibernate.criterion.Example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.html) to get the behavior you're describing:

```
    List results = session.createCriteria(MyObj.class)
        .add( Example.create(inputObj) )
        .list();
```

This is described in [section 15.4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) of the Reference Documentation.